# ¿Cómo capturar teclas para accesos rápidos en Windows Form C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, hotkeys

Quiero capturar las Teclas F2, F10 y combinaciones como Ctrl + T para crear acceso rápidos a ciertas funciones, he visto este ejemplo en Internet pero no me funciona.

```
private void Colonos_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyData == Keys.F10)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("hola");
   }
}
```

Intenté con este código pero no me sirvió.

Comment: En que componente  programaste ese evento, en un formulario?

Comment: Tengo un formulario y este formulario Tiene un MenuStrip y este a su ves tiene Opciones de menú ToolStripMenuItem.  quiero crear un acceso rápido para que cuando de F2 se active la Opción guardar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para poder acceder a las funcionalidades de un menú mediante **atajos de teclado**, debes marcar cada ítem del menú e ir al **inspector de objetos** y en la propiedad **ShortcutKeys** escoger la combinación de teclas que desees, y la propiedad **ShowShorcutsKeys** si le pones el valor **true**, mostrará la visualización de la combinación de teclas en el ítem del menú.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También puedes acceder a los menús por el teclado anteponiendo el carácter **&**(ampersand) al texto que le pones al menú, ej., tienes un Menú que su texto es Archivo, y este a su vez tiene un ítem llamado Guardar, si pusiéramos como texto **&Archivo** y **&Guardar**, decimos que apretando las teclas **Alt + A**, accedemos al menú Archivo, y **Alt + G**, accedemos al ítem Guardar, el caracter **&** puede ir delante de cualquier letra ej., **Archi&vo**, sería **Alt + V**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes usar tanto **Shortcut** como esto último que te explico para acceder a los menú, y una opción no excluye a la otra, por tanto en un menú puedes tener estas dos características sin problema.

No hay que escribir una línea de código para lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo un método que captura la pulsación de las teclas

en éste caso te pongo dos teclas de ejemplo, F2 y F10, captura tanto el evento al presionar la tecla como el evento al soltar la misma

La solución está sacada de éste block:

[Enlace a capturas de teclas](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook)

Basa su funcionamiento en la utilización de la clase globalKeyboardHook, que tendrás seguramente que instalar descargando los paquetes de la misma. Ojo, que a mí me instaló unos paquetes y y luego me sugería cambiar globalKeyboardHook por GlobalKeyboardHook, pero la que funcionaría sería como pongo en el código, con minúscula

Código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Utilities;

public partial class Form1 : Form {
    globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.F2);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.F10);
        gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
        gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);
    }

    void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        lstLog.Items.Add("Up\t" + e.KeyCode.ToString());
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        lstLog.Items.Add("Down\t" + e.KeyCode.ToString());
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```